# Are there free records of separate piano notes in .wav files for instance?

Tags: audio, synthesizer, piano

I'm trying to find some piano sound bank -for my childish experiments with sound - the most desired form is of course a number of .wav files, each one corresponding to a piano key - being a record of a real piano key sound.
Is it possible to find such a thing? Preferably without any copyright issues.

Answer (score 11):

[The university of Iowa](http://theremin.music.uiowa.edu/MISpiano.html) has recordings of separate piano notes in `.aiff` format.

Comment: @RobertHarvey: yea it seems this will be easier. I don't get why they didn't make an archive of all the files, but oh well, there's always DownThemAll.

Comment: To normalize those recordings for length, volume, and start time, try: `ffmpeg -i Piano.ff.Gb7.aiff -af loudnorm,silenceremove=start_periods=1:start_silence=0.05:start_threshold=-40dB,afade=out:st=3:d=1.5,afade=in:st=0:d=0.05 -to 4.5 out.m4a`

Answer (score 9):

It should be easy enough to find a [SoundFont](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SoundFont) that contains what you want, [like this one](http://zenvoid.org/audio.html).

Note that most SoundFonts bend each sample a few notes each way to cover the entire keyboard.  If you want one .WAV for each note on the piano, the [Fruity Loops Studio](http://www.image-line.com/downloads/flstudiodownload.html) demo allows you to make the files by just opening the piano roll, making the note then saving it in whatever format you like.

Comment: I didn't know the term. Thanks a lot!

Comment: As far as I understand now, soundFonts don't contain all notes - I mean not the whole piano range, but a number of notes that could be used to create sounds of all other notes by changing the pitch in between DFT and reverse DFT procedures or something of that kind - but still changing the pitch. Don't want to sound picky, but I continue my search. Though SoundFonts turned to be an interesting thing.

Comment: @Art: did you find anything? I'm looking for the same thing

Comment: @houbysoft: What about the one I linked? :D

Comment: @RobertHarvey: The SoundFont doesn't seem to have all notes -- I'd prefer to have discrete `.wav` for instance, for every note.

Comment: @houbysoft: Fruity Loops Studio Demo allows you to make the files by just opening the piano roll, making the note then saving it in whatever format you like.  http://www.image-line.com/downloads/flstudiodownload.html

Comment: Could you please provide me some more specific instructions on how to do that? The interface of Fl studio is extremely confusing for somebody who's never seen it before :) Basically if I want 88 wavs, one for each note on the keyboard, how can FL studio help me do that?

Comment: @houbysoft: Presumably you would need to "play" the note in the piano roll, and save the result to a .WAV file.  You would have to do this for all 88 notes.  If this seems too arduous, try [the procedure described here](http://www.ehow.com/how_5150123_convert-sf-wav.html) (I haven't tested it, so I don't know if it really works or not).

Answer (score 2):

I think this might help https://archive.org/details/SynthesizedPianoNotes

You can search in archive.org for more

Answer (score 1):

The [Yamaha OLPC Disklavier set](http://wiki.laptop.org/go/Free_sound_samples#The_Zenph_Studios_Yamaha_Disklavier_Pro_Piano_Multisamples_for_OLPC) also exists.

Answer (score 1):

I found the correct resource: https://www.reddit.com/r/piano/comments/3u6ke7/heres_some_midi_and_mp3_files_for_individual/

From author SingleInfinity:

> Here's some midi and mp3 files for individual notes. from a3-a6,
> inclusive. So, for a generative art class, I've had a project that
> required me to get some individual notes for a program to play. I
> searched for decent samples all over, but failed to find anything
> (free) that was in any way useful. I took it upon myself to make my
> own (which was a pain). The notes included go from a3 to a6,
> inclusive. Sharps are denoted via a hyphen, ie a4 = a, 4th octave, a-4
> = a sharp, 4th octave.
>
> For anyone wondering how this was done, here's the rundown.
>
> Recorded all of the notes into a single midi file via my keyboard and
> Anvil Studio.
>
> Split each midi note into singular notes in Audacity.
>
> Converted each midi file to mp3 via solmire.com.
>
> And then clipped each(2 second) resulting mp3 file into a 0.65 second
> mp3 file containing the note (and not much else).
>
> So, after all my hard work, I figured I'd save some other poor sap
> from having to do the same, so I'll share my work here.
>
> Midi files:
> http://www.mediafire.com/download/zp8brp1f6q777b1/Midi_Notes.rar
>
> mp3 files:
> http://www.mediafire.com/download/zd1mqtazulgv28a/mp3_Notes.rar
>
> Hope this helps someone.
>
> I also realize random download links can scare some people, so if
> someone could verify the files in a VM or something and vouch, that'd
> be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

I think this repo should do the job for you :
https://github.com/nemo0/js-piano/tree/main/notes